# "object is not a function" error when try to get value by calling WebAPI in KonckoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I'm working with KnockoutJS to create an online tool. Inside the view model there is a computed property which calls a WebAPI to fetch remotely calculated values, my approach is trying to call the WebAPI via jquery .ajax call, as the code snippet shown below

It generates "object is not a function" error at the spots where I try to declare transferring the parameters, which sit inside the same view model, to WebAPI.

Please show me a way to do it correctly, thanks

```html
<input id="interestRate" type="text" data-bind="value: interestRate" />
<input id="amountBeingWithdrawn" type="text" data-bind="value: amountBeingWithdrawn" />
<strong id="calculatedFee" data-bind="text: calculateResult().CalculatedFee"></strong>
<strong id="adminFee" data-bind="text: calculateResult().Interest"></strong>
```

```js
    var apiUrl = "/api/Calculator"

    var calculatorModel = function () {

        this.interestRate = ko.observable(7.5);
        this.amountBeingWithdrawn = ko.observable(10000);

        this.calculateResult = ko.computed(function () {
            return $.ajax({
                url: apiUrl,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    InterestRateContracted: this.interestRate(), //ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
                    AmountBeingWithdrawn: this.amountBeingWithdrawn() //ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    return {
                        Fee: result.CalculatedFee,
                        Interest: result.Interest
                    };
                }
            });
        }).extend({ async: true });

    }

    var calculator = new calculatorModel();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(calculator);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is something different within the computed, as you haven't told it to be something specific.  You have two options.  Firstly, keep a reference to `this` on the outer object and use it within the computed:

```
var calculatorModel = function () {
    //keep a reference to the original "this" hanging around
    var self = this;
    this.interestRate = ko.observable(7.5);
    this.amountBeingWithdrawn = ko.observable(10000);

    this.calculateResult = ko.computed(function () {
        return $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                //Here we use the self variable, which will still be referencing
                //the correct object
                InterestRateContracted: self.interestRate(), 
                AmountBeingWithdrawn: self.amountBeingWithdrawn()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                return {
                    Fee: result.CalculatedFee,
                    Interest: result.Interest
                };
            }
        });
    }).extend({ async: true });
}
```

Or secondly, make use of the fact that knockout can [manage `this` for you](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#managing-this):

```
this.calculateResult = ko.computed(function () {
    return $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            InterestRateContracted: this.interestRate(),
            AmountBeingWithdrawn: this.amountBeingWithdrawn()
        },
        success: function (result) {
            return {
                Fee: result.CalculatedFee,
                Interest: result.Interest
            };
        }
    });
}, this).extend({ async: true });
//Note the addition of the this parameter to the computed 
//observable on the above line
```

Comment: Cracker! Thank you James, I gave your second solution a go, it worked a treat